# Question regarding this notice in Clarity extension

Tags: stack, blockchain, smartcontracts, clarity-lang, stacks-blockchain

Question regarding this notice in Clarity extension v0.7.1

```
(define-public (lock (new-beneficiary principal) (unlock-at uint) (amount uint))
```

Returns:
'source of untrusted input here'

```
(var-set beneficiary (some new-beneficiary))
```

Returns:
'use of potentially unchecked data'

Any suggestions how to resolve these notices? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These are just warning flags created by Clarinet letting you know that you have some unchecked data. If you are okay with having the unchecked data, you can mark that using a few flags provided by Clarinet: https://docs.hiro.so/clarinet/feature-guides/analyze-with-check-checker

Otherwise, provide some sort of check to make sure the data is what you are expecting.

Comment: this link leads to a Page Not Found

Comment: the updated URL should be:

https://docs.hiro.so/clarinet/guides/analyze-with-check-checker

Answer (score 0):

right above your expression, add the comment:

`;; #[allow(unchecked_data)]`